# PF Nat over OpenVPN Client

Tags: openvpn, freebsd, pf

I have FreeBSD 12.1-RELEASE router with 3 interfaces:

- LAN HOME(192.168.22.)
- LAN WORK(192.168.11.)
- WAN(1.2.3.4)

My router connect to NordVPN over OpenVPN as a client (creates new TUN0 with address 10.8.0.3)

I want now to nat only one host from LAN_HOME ( 192.168.22.30) to internet over the NordVPN.

I try to setup this with PF and this rule :

```
nat on tun0 inet from 192.168.22.30/32 to any -> 10.8.0.3
```

with no luck.

Thank you, for any advice.

Comment: You would need policy-routing in place, lookup the `route-to` in `man pf.conf`. On FreeBSD it should be normally working together with `nat`, IIRC.

Comment: I check this route-to, but i can't set it up correctly i think.